# pyOpenCL not running, no error

Tags: pyopencl

I am trying to get started with pyOpenCL and I'm running into an issue running the examples. I simplified the code to try to figure out what is going on to what I have below. When I run the code it will only print 1. It will not produce any error. The same occurs if I just call cl.create_some_context().

I am running windows 7, python 2.7 with AMD CPU and ATI GPU. I have updated my drivers. From what I can find my GPU does not support OpenCL but my CPU does.

CPU: AMD Athlon II X2 250

GPU: ATI Radeon HD 4600

```
import pyopencl as cl
import numpy

print 1
cl.get_platforms()
print 2
cl.create_some_context()
print 3
```

output:

```
1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get more information on your problem - you might want to set up your context in the more explicit way.

Get the list of devices on your platform:

```
pyopencl.get_devices(device_type = device_type.ALL)
```

Select a preferred device:

```
for found_device in my_platform.get_devices():
    if pyopencl.device_type.to_string(found_device.name) == 'GPU':
        device = found_device
```

Create a context from device type, or a list of devices (device_type : ALL, GPU, CPU):

```
context = pyopencl.Context(devices = None | [dev1, dev2], dev_type = None )
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Test This Code**

```
import pyopencl as cl
platforms = cl.get_platforms()
len(platforms)
gpu_devices = platforms[0].get_devices(cl.device_type.GPU)
gpu_devices

cpu_devices = platforms[0].get_devices(cl.device_type.CPU)
cpu_devices
```